# Azure Durable Function - Unavailable port

Tags: azure-durable-functions

While working on Azure Durable, if I have to restart the service on my local. I get this error (snapshot) - "Port 7071 is unavailable. Close the porcess using that port or specify another port by using --port".

To get over this issue, I have to wait for a couple of minutes after I have stopped the service and then start it. In case it does not work, I will wait for another 2-3 minutes and try again. Although the workaround works on a consistent basis, it's still a pain.

Anyone knows of a better solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/blob/9a22f71c3b0aef6be8c3dbe9ad758e5f9713386b/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/Helpers/NetworkHelpers.cs mentions a possible race condition here.

Comment: So it's a bug. If yes, can this also happen on Prod after a new deployment or restart of server?

Comment: Hitting this all the time right now in development. Was there any mention of a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

October 19th 2018 (the month after original question posted) a fix was committed. 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/commit/b34b693ff6b031dffeb68fb01f6bdb47d963e18f

Original github issue : https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1000

Seems the solution is to wait a moment between debug sessions.